# How to make multiple group counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display counts for 2 fields using group query.

Here is the table and the scenario:
TABLE

```
email            campaign
test@test.com    25
test@test.com    25
test@test.com    26
```

The query should fetch this for me. It should tell that test@test.com is repeated 3 times and there are 2 unique campaigns for that email.

Result: test@test.com email_count=3 campaign_count=2

I tried many group queries but none of them helped.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward, `COUNT()` allows `DISTINCT` keyword to count only unique values.

```
SELECT email, 
       COUNT(*) email_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT campaign) Unique_count
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY email
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64eca/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT email,SUM(DISTINCT  campaign),COUNT(email)  FROM `table` GROUP BY email
```

Comment: `SUM(campaign)` will yield 76 based on the records given.

Comment: @JW웃 yes i have shown the `SUM` of campaign and count of `email`

Comment: the OP wants to count the number of unique values for campaign. so it should be `2` since the unique values are `25 and 26`.

Comment: What if i replace `SUM` with `COUNT` then there will be minor difference b/w mine answer and yours :)